# How do I make timer notifications on Expo?

Tags: react-native, timer, notifications, expo

I want to add a notification that displays a timer on my Expo App.

I already tried customizing timestamps for android with Notifee, however its font is too small on Samsung Galaxies.

( This is the snippet )

```
await notifee.displayNotification({
 title: langObj('WorkoutMaker').notification,
 id: '00',
 android: {
      channelId,
      onlyAlertOnce: true,
      smallIcon: 'notification_icon',
      autoCancel: false,
      ongoing: true,
      color: 'red',
      importance: AndroidImportance.DEFAULT,
      visibility: AndroidVisibility.PUBLIC,
      showChronometer: true,
      chronometerDirection: 'down',
      timestamp: Date.now() + time * 1000,
      timeoutAfter : time * 1000,
      pressAction: {
           id: 'default',
      },
},
```